# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении:

*Вдруг одна из досок покачнулась, появились силуэты вещей, и, как чёрт из табакерки, выскочило лохматое существо.*

Не могу понять: фразеологизм "как чёрт из табакерки" можно заменить словом "неожиданно ", поэтому, вроде, запятую можно не ставить; может быть, эта фраза является вводной или сравнительным оборотом, и нужны запятые?

Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

А если рассмотреть такой вариант:

**Вдруг** одна из досок покачнулась, появились силуэты вещей  и, **как чёрт из табакерки**, выскочило лохматое существо.

1) Наречие "вдруг" является общим элементом, поэтому запятая перед "и" не ставится.

2) Как чёрт из табакерки - неполное сравнительное придаточное с пропущенным сказуемым (как черт **выскакивает** из табакерки), поэтому оно обособляется.

Примеры неполных сравнительных предложений:

Гостиная набита гостями, как подушка пером. 
Высохшие стулья потрескивали, как дрова в камине. 
Дни отрываются от меня, как листики от дерева.

Answer (score 1):

Как Вы сами правильно рассудили, это фразеологизм. А он относится к пяти случаям [отсюда](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183), когда оборот с "как" не обособляется. Поэтому, я думаю, правильно так:

*Вдруг одна из досок покачнулась, появились силуэты вещей, и как чёрт из табакерки выскочило лохматое существо.*

Comment: Прошла по ссылке "отсюда", там сказано:  "Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК в пяти случаях: 
2. Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав фразеологизма, например: Во время обеда она сидела как на иголках.

Comment: Как чёрт из табакерки - это фразеологизм. Всё равно спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Да, Вы правы! Вы даже это упомянули, а я и прочитал невнимательно, и сам решил, что это не фразеологизм почему-то.(( Меняю ответ.